# Deploy existing workflow rule from sandbox to production org using change set

Tags: change-set, workflowrule

Can I deploy workflow rule and field update to production using change set, the workflow rule already there in production org just want to upgrade existing workflow.
Is it possible.???

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can deploy the existing workflow rule.

workflow rule will use the unique name to call the field update and not the record id. That way you can maintain consistency of workflows moving form one org to another.

Comment: So, I need to select both workflow rule as well as field update right.?

Comment: You can either deploy both workflow rule and field update.
in case, workflow rule is already in production you just need to deploy the field update if there is no change in workflow rule. It will automatically reflect in same workflow.